# How to add drag and drop behavior on dynamically created images

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone 8 application in which i created some images on a canvas dynamically, Now i want to add drag and drop behaviour on every dynamically created image.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{      
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
    img.Name = imgDefaultName + ctr.ToString();
    img.Height = 220;
    img.Width = 160;

    MyCanvas.Children.Add(img);
    Canvas.SetLeft(img, left);
    Canvas.SetTop(img, top);
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/eclipse.png", UriKind.Relative));

    // left = left + 100;

}
```

My xaml look like this

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0">
     <!--<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">-->
         <Canvas Name="MyCanvas" Background="WhiteSmoke" Width="483">
         </Canvas>
     <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
 </Grid>
```

Comment: I've removed a tag from question's title - please note than in most cases questions [shouldn't include tag in their title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 0):

You must handle the `UIElement.ManipulationStarted`, `UIElement.ManipulationDelta`, `UIElement.ManipulationCompleted` events for your images.

Check [THIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/07/10/drag-amp-drop-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone.aspx) example.